# Flutter Web app stuck on startup and splash screen

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web

Flutter web app stuck on startup.
Cause:

```
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'ui.webOnlyWarmupEngine': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 163..
```

Same problem on `Chrome` and on command `flutter run -d web-server` and open using Brave Browser localhost page.
How I can avoid it? I remove splash screen from code and `pubspec.yaml`, then run `flutter clean`, but this error still exist.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
Same problem on:
`Flutter version 3.3.0 on channel stable`
and
`Flutter version 3.5.0-6.0.pre.64 on channel master`